# Wordpress URL unexpected redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

My site URL is : http://abcd.com/index.php

I don't understand why, when I am opening :
http://abcd.com/index.php/welcome/ I am redirected to :
http://abcd.com/welcome/
which doesn't exist and displays a 404

My .htaccess is :

```html
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /index.php/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What do you think is wrong ?

Regards,

Comment: Why you are trying to open `http://abcd.com/index.php/welcome/`? You should not open `index.php` script directly. It's just for hidden routing of rewrited URLs by `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

I had used a permalink structure like /index.php/%postname%/ 
and it was working, but the other formats no.
I made the other permalink format works by changing my config in my virtualhost, adding the default wordpress .htaccess content. restarted apache, my permalinks worked as well as all the other stuff...
10hours of pain